# Domain name not working in AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, dns, passenger

I had previously hosted my domain in a different instance in a different aws account but for some reason I had to delete that aws account and create a new one. I am now trying to host my domain in the new instance. So I went to my registrar`s account and deleted all the nameservers from the domain name and added the new nameserver. Then I added my domain into the hosted zone in aws.
[image]

After waiting for 2 3 hrs my domain is still now working but if I visit the public IP it works.

I have edited the /etc/hosts file and added domainname.com there and also I have edited the /sites-available/default and added

```
    server {
#        passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;
        rails_env development; # add this if you get error like “Incomplete response received from application” from nginx / passenger
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name fuitter.com, *.fuitter.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/maggie/public/;

        # You must explicitly set 'passenger_enabled on', otherwise
        # Passenger won't serve this app.
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
```

I have restarted my nginx server but still it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, your nameservers are still pointing to orderbox-dns.com nameservers.

You need to goto the registry where your domain is registerd and tell it that Route53 is going to manage your DNS; those NS records you show above should be entered at the registrar as your nameservers.

[image]

Comment: so my friend mistakenly had added those NS records in the registrar. I have again updated the NS records in the registrar and still the domain is not working.

Comment: when I ran whois on fuitter.com I did get my NS records. but why is my domain still not working. Will it take 24-48 hrs quota or something?

Comment: hey, I have made some changes to the question. please take a look at it.

Comment: Your site comes up for me now with your domain.

Comment: but it is not working for me. I have tried doing fuitter.com and www.fuitter.com

Comment: you probably have dns cached in your browser; clear your dns cache and/or try later. BTW: www.fuitter doesn't work, only fuitter.com

Comment: yes finally it is working in mine too, now I need to figure out why is www.fuitter.com not working.,